# Recursive query with parent-child relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I am trying to make a recursive query in SQL Server, that display data hierarchically. Here is the structure of the table

```
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [varchar(100)] NOT NULL,
    [Parent_Id] [int] NULL,
```

Each product has a parent. The column Parent_Id content the id of the parent. The parent_id is null for root products.

I want to make a sql query that display products hierarchically. The following image is an example of how the products could be organized.

[image]

Products can have products childs.

For the picture above, the query result should be like the following :

```
id name      parent_id
1  P1        NULL
2  P2        NULL
3  P2-1      2
4  P2-2      2
5  P2-3      2
6  P2-3-1    5
7  P2-3-2    5
8  P3        NULL
9  P3-1      8
```

Here is the request  I wrote to achieve it :

```
with tree as (select * from products
               union all
               select * from tree where parent_id = tree.id
             )
select * from tree;
```

But I get a result similar to the following:

```
1  P1        NULL
2  P2        NULL
8  P3        NULL
3  P2-1      2
4  P2-2      2
5  P2-3      2
9  P3-1      8
6  P2-3-1    5
7  P2-3-2    5
```

**What I want is to group each products sibling so that each product is displayed under its direct parent.**

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  For instance, `parent_id` is declared `not null`, but it is `null` in the sample data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just another option using the data type `hierarchyid`

There are some additional features and functions associated with [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/getancestor-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

**Example**

```
-- Optional See 1st WHERE
Declare @Top int = null  --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 2

;with cteP as (
      Select ID
            ,parent_id 
            ,Name 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat('/',ID,'/'))
      From   YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(parent_id ,-1) else ID end
      --Where parent_id is null  -- Use this where if you always want the full hierarchy
      Union  All
      Select ID  = r.ID
            ,parent_id  = r.parent_id 
            ,Name   = r.Name
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat(p.HierID.ToString(),r.ID,'/'))
      From   YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.parent_id  = p.ID)
Select Lvl   = HierID.GetLevel()
      ,ID
      ,parent_id
      ,Name  
 From cteP A
 Order By A.HierID
```

**Results**

```
Lvl ID  parent_id   Name
1   1   NULL        P1
1   2   NULL        P2
2   3   2           P2-1
2   4   2           P2-2
2   5   2           P2-3
3   6   5           P2-3-1
3   7   5           P2-3-2
1   8   NULL        P3
2   9   8           P3-1
```

Just for fun, If I set `@Top` to 2, the results would be

```
Lvl ID  parent_id   Name
1   2   NULL        P2
2   3   2           P2-1
2   4   2           P2-2
2   5   2           P2-3
3   6   5           P2-3-1
3   7   5           P2-3-2
```

Comment: A note - given the table's structure, the hierarchyid needs to be calculated just-in-time. But! If you modify your application to maintain it as your data changes, you can use it straight away.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correct and you have the result you want but just unordered, you should be able to just order the result by name.

```
with tree as (select * from products
               union all
               select * from tree where parent_id = tree.id
             )
select * from tree order by name asc;
```

Comment: relation "tree" does not exist

Answer (score -1):

Construct the path in the recursive query.  The following does this as a string with fixed length ids:

```
with tree as (
      select p.id, p.name, p.parentid,
             format(p.parentid, '0000') as path
      from products p
      where p.parentid is null
      union all
      select p.id, p.name, p.parentid,
             concat(cte.path, '->', format(p.id, '0000')
      from tree join
           products p
      where p.parent_id = t.id
     )
select *
from tree;
```

Comment: Thak you for the answer. But i was looking for a solution that will not require a lot of code on the c# side. So finally, the solution of John, it the one that match my need;

Comment: @THEHOLYSPIRIT . . . John often comes up with very clever and appropriate solutions.  However, I didn't realize that this would cause much coding on the application side.